# How to install Oracle Instant Client on a Mac?

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle12c, instantclient

How to install Oracle Instant Client Version 12.1.0.2 (64-bit) on a Mac (OS X 10.11.5)

I have downloaded version 12.1.0.2 (64-bit) version and unzipped the file.

I now have the following files under /downloads/instantclient:

```
libclntsh.dylib.12.1
libclntshcore.dylib.12.1
libnnz12.dylib
libocci.dylib.12.1
libociei.dylib
libocijdbc12.dylib
libons.dylib
liboramysql12.dylib
ojdbc6.jar
ojdbc7.jar
uidrvci
xstreams.jar
adrci
BASIC_README
genezi
```

I don't have the slightest idea how to go from this to a working version of Instant Client so I can connect to a db from the CLI.  The instructions on Oracles website seem to be overly complicated.

I have found a few blogs detailing the installation method, but they all seem to be from previous version of Instant Client.  Out of desperation, I downloaded a previous version of Instant Client, but still seemed to be missing files referred to in the tutorial.

Does anyone know how I can get Oracle Instant Client on my Mac?

Answer (score 41):

HomeBrew saved me. I did not figure out the environment path.

*Per referenced blog this Answer (see bottom) was originated from:*

> (Update 10/06/2020: Step 1 is no longer necessary, just run the brew commands!)

1. Download the two files below from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html.

This is necessary because of Oracle licenses.

`instantclient-basic-macos.x64–11.2.0.4.0.zip` and
`instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64–11.2.0.4.0.zip`

Put the files in `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew`

---

PS:

> in the latest versions of HomeBrew replace the above location `~/Library/Caches/HomeBrew` with `~/Library/Caches/HomeBrew/downloads`.
>
> And also rename the downloaded files with the names suggested by HomeBrew.
>
> Thanks to @manuka_m

---

**2. Next run the following commands**

> $ brew tap InstantClientTap/instantclient
>
> $ brew install instantclient-basic
>
> $ brew install instantclient-sqlplus

Originated from [Joost van Wollingen's doc](https://vanwollingen.nl/install-oracle-instant-client-and-sqlplus-using-homebrew-a233ce224bf)

Comment: In the terminal @SunishthaSingh . Homebrew is Mac related

Comment: I don't have ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew
 in my Mac. Where is it?

Comment: Please note in the latest versions of HomeBrew replace the above location `~/Library/Caches/HomeBrew` with `~/Library/Caches/HomeBrew/downloads`. And also rename the downloaded files with the names suggested by HomeBrew.

Comment: "With the names suggested by HomeBrew" -- what does this mean? Where would I see such suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, not maintained. I am not a DB developer now.

Comment: See [Janusz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711482/how-to-install-oracle-instant-client-on-a-mac/58815844#58815844). Joost updated [the instructions](https://vanwollingen.nl/install-oracle-instant-client-and-sqlplus-using-homebrew-a233ce224bf) in 2020 - the manual download step is no longer needed. You only need the `brew tap` and `brew install` steps.

Answer (score 24):

There are [multiple files available for download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html). From the files you listed you have only downloaded and unzipped the 'basic' package.

To run the CLI (by which I assume you mean SQL*Plus) you need that package as well - the fourth in the list, titled "Instant Client Package - SQL*Plus: Additional libraries and executable for running SQL*Plus with Instant Client".

The packages are arranged such that if you unzip all the ones you need from the same place they all put their files in the same directory. Unfortunately that doesn't quite work if you use Safari and have it set to open certain downloaded files; each zip file is expanded into a separate folder, with incremented names. And it deletes the zip files afterwards.

You can either disable that automatic unzipping and do it manually, or copy the files from the individual folders into a common one.

You may also need to create a symbolic link for the main client library; from inside that folder (in Terminal) you would do:

```
ln -s libclntsh.dylib.12.1 libclntsh.dylib
```

You can put that combined folder anywhere you like. You then need to add the full path to that folder to your PATH and environment variable - you can add that to your .bash_profile so you don't need to do it manually.

Once you've done that you can execute `sqlplus` from anywhere.

So to summarise:

1. If you're using Safari, disable automatic opening of the zip files; from Safari->Preferences->General untick the 'Open "safe" files after downloading' checkbox.
2. [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) instantclient-basic-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip and instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
3. In Terminal go to your Downloads directory.
4. Unzip both files:

   ```
   MacBook:Downloads alex$ unzip instantclient-basic-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
   Archive:  instantclient-basic-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/BASIC_README  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/adrci  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/genezi  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.dylib.12.1  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/libclntshcore.dylib.12.1  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/libnnz12.dylib  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/libocci.dylib.12.1  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/libociei.dylib  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/libocijdbc12.dylib  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/libons.dylib  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/liboramysql12.dylib  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/ojdbc6.jar  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/ojdbc7.jar  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/uidrvci  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/xstreams.jar  
   MacBook:Downloads alex$ unzip instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
   Archive:  instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/SQLPLUS_README  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/glogin.sql  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/libsqlplus.dylib  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/libsqlplusic.dylib  
     inflating: instantclient_12_1/sqlplus
   ```
5. Optionally rename and/or move the `instantclient_12_1` directory to somewhere more permanent.
6. Add the location to your path in your current session, and also in your shell profile/resource file to make it take effect on every login:

   ```
    export PATH=$HOME/Downloads/instantclient_12_1:$PATH
   ```
7. Enjoy.

   ```
   MacBook:Downloads alex$ export PATH=$HOME/Downloads/instantclient_12_1:$PATH
   MacBook:Downloads alex$ which sqlplus
   /Users/alex/Downloads/instantclient_12_1/sqlplus
   MacBook:Downloads alex$ sqlplus

   SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Jun 9 16:29:49 2016

   Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

   Enter user-name:
   ```

---

El Capitan added system integrity protection (SIP), and one side effect of that is that exporting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work. That could affect running SQL*Plus from a shell script, for example. There are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35268217/266304) for the 11g instant client. The installation notes at the bottom of the download page have changed since I last did this, and it now says to hard link the library files to the user's `~/lib` directory to avoid that issue. Fortunately it looks like you don't need to worry about that with the 12c client - they've fixed the way it's built.

Comment: Will give this a shot and report back, thanks for the info.

Comment: So two things I want to clarify.  1.  I can drop all instant client files (including sqlplus) into a single directory?  and 2.  I just go into my bash profile (in this case .zshrc) and add the instantclient directory path to my $PATH ?  I just want to clarify because it's still not working.

Comment: For (1) yes, they have to be unzipped into the same directory, for the library dependencies to work. For (2) are you exporting the updated PATH? And can you run `sqlplus` from the directory those files are in, but not anywhere else?

Comment: no matter which directory I am in, if i type sqlplus in terminal, it says "command not found",  I have export PATH in my .zshrc with the path to the instantclient directory, which is /Users/bdonna/Downloads/instantclient_12_1

Comment: Have you also done that export in your current shell, or re-sourced your .zshrc, or started a new shell? Adding it to the file makes it automatic on next log in, guess that wasn't obvious... And if you're in the directory you can do `./sqlplus`, I forgot it excludes the current directory by default.

Comment: So I can do something like this for the path line right?  export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/bdonna/.rbenv/shims:/Users/bdonna/Downloads/instantclient_12_1

Comment: @ben - yes, though it's more usual to extend the existing value with `export PATH=$HOME/Downloads/instantclient_12_1:$PATH`. (Double-quotes aren't needed, but should be balanced if you use them - that was probably a copy/pasrte glitch.) Just noticed I had an invalid path inmy answer so I've changed that.

Comment: @ben - from your new question, this still isn't working for you? Not sure what you're doing differently, I pasted exactly what I did installing from scratch, from fresh downloads.

Comment: I think the issue I had was I could not establish connection via jdbc with sqlplus,  it sounds like sqlcl has better support for jdbc?  I have installed sqlcl as you suggested in response to my other post, and I am now trying to establish connection.

Comment: @ben - SQL\*Plus isn't Java so isn't using JDBC, but does allow similar URLs ('easy connect'), e.g. `sqlplus user/password@//host:1521/service`. SQLcl is is written in Java and runs in a JVM so it is using JDBC (as is SQL Developer). But anything you can connect to from SQL Developer you can connect to from SQL\*Plus. Maybe you had network/firewall issues?

Comment: Yea that makes sense, the only way I could connect in SQLDeveloper was with jdbc for some reason, so since SQLplus doesnt support jdbc, it was a no go.  I am now using sqlcl, but unable to establish connection via jdbc, see my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843426/why-cant-i-connect-via-jdbc-using-sqlcl

Comment: SQL Develoepr *only* uses JDBC. From that question were you putting  `vdbsl14` in the connection panel's Service Name box, and that got the same ORA-12514? If you'd put that in the SID box instead it would probably have worked.

Comment: The path above gave me errors. In case it helps anyone else I used: `export PATH="/Users/zaheeram//Downloads/instantclient_12_1:$PATH"`

Comment: I created an installation shell script to automate the install instructions
https://gist.github.com/rcbop/d8d868f4a100e1ac4b36c6ca93a5aeaf
You just need to place the sdk and basic instant client zip files in the same place as this script and run it as root!

Comment: I don't rename my files. I put them on my home. I unzip both by terminal. Then, I wrote: 
export PATH="/Users/adrianagiuliano/Desktop/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-18.1.0.0.0.zip:$PATH"

but when I wrote: which sqlplus 

I have: -bash: which: command not found

I tried also with: which sqlplus /Users/adrianagiuliano/Desktop/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-18.1.0.0.0.zip

The answer is the same. With is a command not found.

Comment: @Adryr83 - you don't put the **zip file** in your path, you put the expanded folder in your path. That folder has the `sqlplus` executable in it.

Comment: Ok, @AlexPoole, I write: 
export PATH="/Users/adrianagiuliano/Desktop/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-18.1.0.0.0:$PATH"
and then:
which sqlplus /Users/adrianagiuliano/Desktop/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-18.1.0.0.0

But when I try the command: sqlplus, I see: 

sqlplus: command not found

Comment: @Adryr83 - isn't your unzipped directory called `instantclient_18_1`, rather than `instantclient-basic-macos.x64-18.1.0.0.0`?

Comment: Ok, @AlexPoole, now it's better but not fine. I wrote the right commands, but when I wrote sqlplus, the answer of my terminal is: 

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclntsh.dylib.18.1
  Referenced from: /Users/adrianagiuliano/Desktop/instantclient_18_1/sqlplus
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

Answer (score 22):

Using **Homebrew** (https://brew.sh/) simple as that:

```
$ brew tap InstantClientTap/instantclient
$ brew install instantclient-basic
$ brew install instantclient-sqlplus
```

No additional libs needed in my case. Depending on your shell - `rehash` could be needed.

Comment: Actually I found this incomplete, ORACLE_HOME needs to be set.

Comment: Same issue for me - and I cannot figure out what to set it to.

Comment: Anyone know what ORACLE_HOME should be set to when using Brew?

Comment: @jmc42 something like: `ORACLE_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/instantclient-basic/19.8.0.0.0dbru`

Comment: If you need additional utilities like expdp (data pump export), you'll also want to `brew install instantclient-tools`

Answer (score 0):

Within SQLdeveloper you will find SQLplus, that works out of the box like on Windows.

[image: SQLDeveloper example]

(Should start like this)

If you move the app under Application and manage to start up the SQLdeveloper-client you cant fint it here, called sql:

```
/Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sql
```

To directly login, run sql and exit:

```
sql username/password@ADDRESS_TO_DB:1521/SID @/path/to/your/pls_file_containing_sql/test.pls
```

Remember to include 'exit;' at the end of your pls-file.

Answer (score 0):

perform the following steps:

1. brew tap InstantClientTap/instantclient
2. brew install instantclient-basic
3. Add these 2 lines to .zshrc:

   ```
     export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/instantclient-basic/19.8.0.0.0dbru/lib

     export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/instantclient-basic/19.8.0.0.0dbru
   ```
4. npm install oracledb -f