# how to log into sql * plus as sysdba?

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to log into the Oracle database. However it displays an error:

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

> ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
> 01033. 00000 - "ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress"
> *Cause: An attempt was made to log on while Oracle is being started up or shutdown.
> *Action: Wait a few minutes. Then retry the operation. Vendor code 1033

So I tried to fix it flowing the instruction on these websites:
https://www.oracletutorial.com/tips/oracle-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress/
[How to install Oracle Instant Client on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711482/how-to-install-oracle-instant-client-on-a-mac)

However, when I tried to log into it, it always appears
'''
TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified error.
'''

Just wondering which username and password should I use to log in successfully?

The errors are shown below. Could anybody pls help me with that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV9Jf.jpg)

Comment: Try to execute `"export ORACLE_SID=your_sid"` or `"setenv ORACLE_SID your_sid"` before executing salplus.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I tried it but the same error still exist, just wondering is it because when I try to build connection to the database, I choose the service name button instead of SID?

Comment: This is what I saw on the website:
Enter user-name: ot@pdborcl as sysdba
Enter password: <password> 
This statement connected to the PDBORCL database using the OT user.         Just wondering what should be username and what should be the database name?

Comment: "net service name is incorrectly specified" has nothing to do with the username or the password you are using. (Those may be wrong too, which you will find out later, after you specify the correct net service name.)

Comment: Are you on the same server as the database is running on?
Are you logged into that server as the Oracle DBA user (usually `oracle`)? 
If no to both/either then you need to get the DBA to look at this, someone who can log onto the server as teh Oracle DBA then connect by setting the ORACLE_SID to teh database SID then ` `sqlplus / as sysdba`.

Comment: And to explain why if you are not on the same server as the DB is on, by default you cannot use `/ as sysdba` on a remote host; imagine someone running SQL Plus on a Windows PC somewhere authenticating that way.